# Why do curried functions require external parameter names?

Tags: swift, currying

Given this simple currying function:

```
func foo(x:Int)(y:Int)->String{
  return "\(x) with \(y)"
}
```

I'd expect to be able to do something like this:

```
let bar = foo(1)
bar(2) //<- error: Missing argument label 'y:' in call
```

If I label the call to `bar` (as in `bar(y:2)`) everything works fine. But I don't understand why the parameter name is necessary. Is there any way to avoid it?

The obvious thing:

`func foo(x:Int)(_ y:Int)->String ...`

does not seem to work.

Comment: Nice!  The issue exists both for a top-level func and for a class method.

Comment: Yeah; even the example of currying in the Swift book shows this up (paste it in, delete the second "manual" currying function, and you get "missing argument label 'b:' in call")

Comment: Wrote this up as rdar://17359591. Please feel free to dupe.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bug, you should file a radar at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

As a confirmation, if you place an underscore, like this

```
func foo(x: Int)(_ y: Int) -> String
```

you get a warning

> Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'y' has no keyword argument name

So it explicitly says that `y` has no external name, but it still requires one when called, which is clearly against the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a compiler bug, your example should work as described in The Swift Programming Language book where they mention declaring curried functions:

```
func addTwoNumbers(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

addTwoNumbers(4)(5) // Returns 9
```

https://bugreport.apple.com

good find!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your currying. Here is my take on it. I have a function foo as follows:

```
func foo(x:Int, y:Int) -> String{
  return "\(x) with \(y)"
}

let bar = foo(1, 2) // gives "1 with 2"
```

I wish to curry this function to 'fix' the value for `x`, so do so as follows:

```
func fooCurry(x:Int) -> (Int -> String) {
  func curry(y:Int) -> String {
    return foo(x, y)
  }
  return curry
}
```

The above returns a new function which can be used as follows:

```
let curriedFoo = fooCurry(1)
let barWithCurry = curriedFoo(2) // gives "1 with 2"
```

The function returned by `fooCurry` has the signature `(Int -> String)`, which means that the parameter does not have an external name.

Comment: what you're doing here is basically currying 'by hand'. `func foo(x: Int)(y: Int) -> String` should work out of the box as a language feature, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best syntax, but if you want to get around it for now, you can use the following for basic curried functions:

```
func foo(x:Int) -> Int -> String {
  return {
    return "\(x) with \($0)"
  }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
let bar = foo(1)
bar(2) //-> 1 with 2
```

Now obviously the problem with this becomes obvious when you want to write a curried function for piping four `Int`s for example:

```
func makerAdders(a:Int)(b:Int)(c:Int)(d:Int) {...}
```

becomes like this:

```
func add(a:Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int {
  return { 
    b in return {
      c in return {
        d in return a + b + c + d 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The inner closures make it a bit better than using inner functions, but again it defeats the purpose of the nice `func add(a:Int)(b:Int)(c:Int)(d:Int) {return a+b+c+d}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bug in the compiler as far as I can tell.  Until it's fixed you can get a properly curried version of any function using these functions (note that I've included cases for two and three arguments, extend at your leisure:

```
func curry<A,B,C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C {
    return { a in { b in return f(a,b) } }
}

func curry<A,B,C,D>(f: (A, B, C) -> D) -> A -> B -> C -> D {
    return { a in { b in { c in return f(a,b,c) } } }
}
```

Just use:

```
curry(addTwoNumbers)(1)(2)
```